# useEffect value remains same after defining it in useEffect in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, use-effect, use-state

I have a component in which I want to fetch an API after rendering, and put a response data in **useState** value.

So, after fetching API I'm trying to **setState** in **useEffect** callback, but nothing works.

```
const [values, setValues] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    fetchValues().then(function(result) {
        setValues(result.data)
    })
}, []);
```

Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: The code looks correct. Make sure `result.data` has some values.

Answer (score 1):

You need to chain another `then` method.
For instance, if the returned data is JSON, to convert it to JS object:

```
const [values, setValues] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    fetchValues().then(result => result.json())
   .then(data => {
       setValues(data)
    })
}, []);
```

If the returned data is text, replace `result.json()` with `result.text()`